# Passing String from JSNI to Java - GWT

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I am having problem passing `String` to a Java method in my GWT project:

```
public final native String waveIt()/*-{
    var instance = this;
    var data = $wnd.Waverecorder.data();
    var strData = data.toString();
    var arr = strData.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var data = arr[i];
        console.log(data);
        instance.@com.mycode.wave.showcase.client.Showcase::updateWave(Ljava/lang/String;)(data.toString());
    }
}-*/;
```

Looking from the console log of Chrome/Firefox I can see that I get the right data (this is the exact log I get):

```
-0.00006103515625
-0.00006103515625
-0.00006103515625
-0.05072021484375
-0.553833007812
 (more data omitted)
```

When the GWT java method received the `data` it is empty. What could be the reason?

Comment: data.toString() ? try passing only `data` as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This method should be void, because you do not return a string - you call a Java method from it.
2. Looking at your code, you don't need var instance = this; and you can remove instance. before @com.
3. You declare var data twice: before the loop and inside the loop. Instead of calling your Java method with data.toString(), you can call it with arr[i].

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> When the GWT java method received the data it is empty.

Are you talking about the string that `waveIt()` should return?

The bug may be that there is no `return` statement in `waveIt()`.